# Python with selenium does not validate my data

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have created a program to validate login data with Python and Selenium, but I have encountered the problem that at the time of running the program and that it enters the data is not validated, even if it is correct.

For example, at the time of starting the promana I pause it and I put the account as invalid, but if I simply open it from the browser if it validates them

Comment: Look from the persons perspective who would want to help you.  Did you provide enough information for someone to understand your issue? not really, there is no code or error message. Please do that first.

Comment: Well when I run selenium and I want to do Loguin on a certain page this does not validate the data, but when I enter from the browser if I validate the login

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.